# How can I write NSAttributedString in rtf file?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, nsattributedstring, rtf

How can I write NSAttributedString in rtf file? i found an ancient answer [How can I save the attributed string (text) into file (swift, cocoa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178895/how-can-i-save-the-attributed-string-text-into-file-swift-cocoa)
I do not quite understand what exactly is required of me, maybe new different way exists somewhere?

Comment: Please take a look at Apple's documentation on NSAttributedString.  There is a function that converts a NSAttributedString to a RFT data stream.  Once you have the data stream write it like any other file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `NSAttributedString`'s `data(from:)` method to convert your attributed string into rtf data.

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func rtf() throws -> Data {
        try data(from: .init(location: 0, length: length),
            documentAttributes: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf,
                                 .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8])
    }
}
```

---

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.attributedText = .init(string: "abc",
                                attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)!])
do {
    let rtfURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("RichTextDocument.rtf")
    try textView.attributedText.rtf().write(to: rtfURL)
    print("saved")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
do {
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(url: fileURL, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
} catch {
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```