# How can NSAttributedString in iOS 15 have " no member 'rtf' "?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, rtf, decoding

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring), from iOS 3.2, NSAttributedString has a method rtf, defined as:

[image]

[image]

```
    var attrText : NSAttributedString = textView.attributedText!
    var docAttr  = [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey : Any]()
    let rtfData = attrText.rtf(
          from: NSMakeRange(0, attrText.length), 
          documentAttributes: docAttr)
    print(String(data: rtfData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "no data")
```

However, in my iOS 15 class (which imports UIKit), in XCode 13.2, when I try to access the method XCode warns me "Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'rtf'.

What's going on?

(Please see attached images).

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1535158-rtf, that method is only available on macOS.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66669175/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR But the link I have above shows it is available in iOS 3.2+

Comment: That is the documentation for NSAttributedString, which *is* available on macOS and iOS. Apparently not all methods are available on both platforms.

Comment: @MartinR Ahhhh.... I see how that works, availability is on a method-by-method basis...  Well bummer that it's not there, but thanks for showing me there's a way to do it!

Comment: @MartinR ... so UIKit is moving forward by the switch from the macOS only rtf()  method to the more generic data() method that handles more types that are now  specified by a dictionary of document-wide attributes including the required .documentType attribute ,which is the way one indicates the  document format, such as RTF... Anyway, thanks for the help.